# How to enter more than one value to textarea using jstl

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, jstl

I'm trying to enter multiple values to textarea using JSTL.

Here is my code.

```
  <label>Resources</label> :
        <c:forEach items="${MEETING_ENTITY}" var="resource">
        <textarea  id="Resources" name="Resources" rows="10" cols="70">
        <c:out value="${resource.resourceEntity.v_resource_name}" ></c:out>
        </textarea>   
        </c:forEach>
```

When this run few text areas generate as the count of the values. How to set every value using "," to a single text area.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling I found the answer.

```
<label>Resources</label> :
<textarea id="Resources" name="Resources" rows="10" cols="70">
    <c:forEach items="${MEETING_ENTITY}" var="resource" varStatus="loop">
        <c:out value="${resource.resourceEntity.v_resource_name}" ></c:out> 
        <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea tag should be before loop -

```
<label>Resources</label> :
<textarea id="Resources" name="Resources" rows="10" cols="70">
    <c:forEach items="${MEETING_ENTITY}" var="resource">
        <c:out value="${resource.resourceEntity.v_resource_name}" ></c:out> 
    </c:forEach>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Sadly still repeating